# computer vision real world size pixel size, opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

My goal is to mount a web camera on a ground vehicle robot and have it recognize lanes and drive in between the lanes. In order to look for the appropriate size lines(lanes) in an image, I am trying to learn how to convert the size of a real world object to image pixel size.

If I mount a usb camera so that its height above the ground is a known fixed vertical distance from the ground, and the angle between the center of the camera lens is fixed, how do I relate the size of a real world object to the number of pixels in the image.

Example: My camera is two feet above the floor. If I define the y axis as pointing upward from the floor, my camera is on the y axis at real world coordinates (x = 0, y = 2 feet, z = 0). It has an angle of 15 degrees below the horizontal xz plane, meaning my camera is pointed downwards toward the floor.

I take an image of some bright green tape on the floor. The tape is 3 feet long and 2 inches wide. How do I translate an object of 3 feet long and 2 inches wide to pixel dimensions? How do I calculate how many pixels represent 3 feet in my image? I am trying to recognize lines of the approximate size.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: A 2D image is a projection of a 3D scene. If you know the distance to each object in the image, simple trigonometry gives the relative scale. Normally, two cameras would be used, with stereo rectification to build a depth map to "understand" the scene in 3D. This *can* be simplified if you can control certain aspects of the scene (like lane lines etc.).

Comment: Err, am I missing something ?  You ask *How do I calculate how many pixels represent 3 feet in my image?* when surely the answer is that you count (in pixels) the length of the 3 foot line in your image and from that (easily) calculate a local pixel:foot ratio. What you are trying to do, I think, is calibrate your camera.